# Python loop | "do-while" over a tree

Tags: python

Is there a more Pythonic way to put this loop together?:

```
while True:
    children = tree.getChildren()
    if not children:
        break
    tree = children[0]
```

UPDATE:
I think this syntax is probably what I'm going to go with:

```
while tree.getChildren():
    tree = tree.getChildren()[0]
```

Comment: Is that really what you want to do?  It only goes down one path from the root to the first leaf, no?

Comment: Nah, it keeps going down, just like the original.

Comment: @johannix:  won't tree.getChildren()[0] raise an IndexError when you get to a leaf?

Comment: No, since it won't get inside the loop. The loop condition will catch that...

Comment: @johannix: what I meant was that your loop will only follow the path from the root to the first "left-most" leaf and then stop.  If you want to loop over the whole tree then you need something else

Comment: Right, but if you look at the original code snippet, this updated version does the same thing.

Comment: Yeah, I get that it does the same thing, I was just wondering if that was the "right" thing.

Comment: @johannix: You want *only* the first branch of the tree!?! That's very unusual... :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
children = tree.getChildren()
while children:
    tree = children[0]
    children = tree.getChildren()
```

It would be easier to suggest something if I knew what kind of collection api you're working with. In a good api, you could probably do something like

```
while tree.hasChildren():
    children = tree.getChildren()
    tree = children[0]
```

Comment: Don't repeat yourself...Pavel's talking about not repeating the 'children = tree.getChildren()' Which is actually why I asked this question to begin with...

Comment: If you don't use the tree variable later, you can merge those two lines in the loop: children = children[0].getChildren()

Comment: Of course he uses the `tree` variable later - `children` is invalid at the end of the loop...

Comment: gnud, that's a good point (the api thing), but hasChildren isn't in the API... Anyways you got me thinking and I got it down to this:
while node.getChildren(): node = node.getChildren()[0]

Comment: As long as getChildren() isn't very expensive, that seems like a good solution

Answer (score 2):

(My first answer suggested to use `iter(tree.getChildren, None)` directly, but that won't work as we are not calling the same `tree.getChildren` function all the time.)

To fix this up I propose a solution using lambda's non-binding of its variables as a possible workaround. I think at this point this solution is not better than any other previously posted:

You can use [iter()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#iter) in it's second sentinel form, using lamda's strange binding:

```
for children in iter((lambda : tree.getChildren()), None):
    tree = children[0]
```

(Here it assumes getChildren() returns `None` when there are no children, but it has to be replaced with whatever value it returns (`[]`?).)

`iter(function, sentinel)` calls function repeatedly until it returns the sentinel value.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really only want the first branch? I'm gonna assume you don't and that you want the whole tree. First I'd do this:

```
def allitems(tree):
    for child in tree.getChildren():
        yield child
        for grandchild in allitems(child):
            yield grandchild
```

This will go through the whole tree. Then you can just:

```
for item in allitems(tree):
    do_whatever_you_want(item)
```

Pythonic, simple, clean, and since it uses generators, will not use much memory even for huge trees.

Comment: with `return` you must mean `yield`

Answer (score 0):

I think the code you have is fine. If you really wanted to, you could wrap it all up in a try/except:

```
while True:
    try:    
        tree = tree.getChildren()[0]
    except (IndexError, TypeError):
        break
```

`IndexError` will work if `getChildren()` returns an empty list when there are no children. If it returns `False` or `0` or `None` or some other unsubscriptable false-like value, `TypeError` will handle the exception.

But that's just *another* way to do it. Again, I don't think the Pythonistas will hunt you down for the code you already have.

Answer (score 0):

Without further testing, I believe this should work:

```
try:    while True: tree=tree.getChildren()[0]
except: pass
```

You might also want to override the `__getitem__()` (the brackets operator) in the `Tree` class, for further neatification.

```
try:    while True: tree=tree[0]
except: pass
```

Comment: No `catch` statement in Python.

Comment: Corrected very soon after I posted :-)